# multiple chain select-list jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

hi i am trying validation multiple select categorie chain list.

```
<select name="cat[]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">categorie 1</option
  <option value="2">categorie 2</option
</select>
<select name="cat[]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="3">categorie 1>A</option
  <option value="4">categorie 1>B</option
</select>
<select name="cat[]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="5">categorie 1>A>A</option
  <option value="6">categorie 1>A>B</option
</select>
```

categorie and sub categorie trigger each other,

my script:

```
$("#myform").validate({
        rules:{
        'cat[]':{required:true,cat_rule:true}
        }
    });

    function cat_rule(value){
        $("select[name=cat[]] option:selected").each(function(){
            return ($(this).val()== '') ? false : true;
        });
    }
    $.validator.addMethod("cat_rule", function (value) {return cat_rule(value)},"Choice categorie!");
```

i wrote this function but not work where is problem?

thanks for helping.

Comment: The root problem is that you have three different input elements all sharing the same `name`.  In order for the jQuery Validate plugin to work properly, each element must have a unique `name`.

Comment: select list names is an array

Comment: Doesn't matter.  When you declare a rule within the `rules` option of the `.validate()` method it needs to match the `name` and it needs to be unique.

Comment: some categorie 1 level, some 2, some 4 level. for this i don't know wich way for me best. maybe class name for selector using, but i don't know this is possible.